# Vagrant SSH can't access shared directory

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I've got a vagrant vm set-up with a project structure on my host machine like so:

```
PlayApps --> App1 -----------> all application/project files
             App2 -----------> ""
             App3 -----------> ""
             (etc..)
             .VagrantFiles --> VagrantFile
                               bootstrap.sh
                               (etc...)
```

I `cd` into my .VagrantFiles directory and then launch the VM.  In my VagrantFile for that VM I'm sharing this directory:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/Shared"
```

with the goal of sharing everything in the PlayApps directory (multiple projects) with the VM.  When I launch the VM and `ssh` in I see the directory /Shared and I can `cd` into it, but when I try to list the contents with `ls -al` I'm getting the following error:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Operation not permitted.
```

When I do `ls -al` on the directory containing /Shared this is what I see (among other directories):

```
d?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? Shared/ and 
d?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? vagrant/
```

I tried to `sudo chmod 666` the /Shared directory, thinking that it was a permissions error, but got the following error:

```
 chmod: cannot access '/Shared': Protocol error
```

Vagrant, ssh, and "ops" in general is fairly new to me so any pointers, suggestions, answers would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you moved/renamed any parent directory of your vagrant box while it was suspended?

If so, run `vagrant halt`, undo any renames, then `vagrant up` and you project dir should be back!

I encountered the exact same issue after renaming the parent dir where my Vagrantfile + project files reside.

Ran additional scenarios which confirm that **renaming a vagrant project's parent directory while the VM is suspended causes this permissions problem**; however, **if you completely shut down the VM with `vagrant halt` your are free to rename**.

Yesterday had a perfectly functional RoR env on Ubuntu precise32 box. Exited the shell, ran `vagrant suspend` and shut down my workstation.

Today day I booted up my workstation (host machine) and renamed the parent directory of my vagrant project, like so:

```
└── ORIGINAL_DIR_NAME
    ├── Vagrantfile
    └── PROJECT

└── NEW_DIR_NAME
    ├── Vagrantfile
    └── PROJECT
```

After, I ran `vagrant up`, `vagrant ssh`. Once in the VM shell I couldn't cd into /vagrant.

`ls -alh /` from the guest shell returned:

```
ls: cannot access /vagrant: Protocol error
[...]
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4.0K Aug  4 21:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Sep 14  2012 usr
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? vagrant
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Aug  4 19:23 var
[...]
```

also tried chmod on `/vagrant` and got this:

```
chmod: cannot access `/vagrant': Protocol error
```

First attempted fix was running `vagrant suspend`, renaming the parent directory back to its original value, then running `vagrant up`. Unfortunately that trashed the entire vagrant VM and it's stuck in vagrant pergatory - won't fully boot or shutdown.

So, the **correct fix** is to exit all vagrant ssh shells, run `vagrant halt` (not suspend) to make sure it's **OFF** (not asleep), and revert any recent renames to parent directories. Then `vagrant up` and see if you can get into `/vagrant`! After that, if you want to rename your folders just `vagrant halt`, rename, and `vagrant up`.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thx

Comment: If you're in my situation where you can't restore the previous configuration, just delete the old vagrant box and restart again `vagrant destroy && rm -rf .vagrant && vagrant up` [more help here](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/625)

Answer (score 5):

Following @musophob's great detailed answer, I realised that if you simply want to move your VagrantFile to a different project folder you always must reload the VM, to fix `/vagrant` access.

Since I end up doing this often enough, I use the shortcut [`vagrant reload` command](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/reload.html) - this simply does `vagrant halt` followed by a `vagrant up` and the VM is ready.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced the **same issue** several times now - though not while renaming the parent directory or moving the Vagrantfile but **when just creating or renaming files at host**. As this happens very infrequently for unknown reasons I was not able to reproduce this deliberately.

Nevertheless, a simple `vagrant reload` **fixes** the problem.